# Can this code be refactores into something shorter?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have the following code

```
let objProvince = paramsData.find(element => element.name === "province")
      if (objProvince) {
        let error = false;
        if (objProvince.value === "VI" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "01") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "AB" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "02") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "A" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "03") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "AL" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "04") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "AV" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "05") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "BA" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "06") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "PM" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "07") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "B" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "08") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "BU" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "09") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "CC" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "10") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "CA" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "11") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "CS" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "12") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "CR" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "13") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "CO" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "14") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "C" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "15") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "CU" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "16") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "GI" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "17") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "GR" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "18") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "GU" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "19") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "SS" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "20") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "H" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "21") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "HU" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "22") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "J" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "23") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "LE" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "24") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "L" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "25") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "LO" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "26") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "LU" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "27") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "M" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "28") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "MA" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "29") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "MU" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "30") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "MA" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "31") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "OR" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "32") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "O" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "33") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "P" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "34") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "GC" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "35") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "PO" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "36") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "SA" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "37") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "TF" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "38") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "S" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "39") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "SG" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "40") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "SE" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "41") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "SO" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "42") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "T" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "43") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "TE" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "44") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "TO" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "45") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "V" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "46") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "VA" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "47") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "BI" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "48") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "ZA" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "49") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "Z" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "50") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "CE" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "51") error = true
        if (objProvince.value === "ML" && value.substring(0, 2) !== "52") error = true

        if (error) {............
```

Which looks huge, but im not really sure how could I shorten this.

I was thinking about doing something like:

```
const provinces = ["VI" , "AB", "A", "AL", "AV", "BA", "PM" , "B" ,"BU", "CC", "CA", "CS", "CR", "CO", "C", "CU", "GI", "GR", "GU", "SS", "H", 
"HU", "J","LE","L","LO","LU","M","MA","MU","MA","OR","O","P","GC","PO","SA","TF","S","SG","SE","SO","T","TE","TO","V","VA","BI","ZA","Z","CE","ML"]


function proviceCheck (_provinceValue) {
    let indexPosition = array.indexOf(_provinceValue) + 1;
    let formatedIndex = ""
    
    if(indexPosition < 10){
        formatedIndex = ('0'+indexPosition).slice(-2);
    }else{
        formatedIndex = indexPosition.toString()
    }
    
    if(provinces.includes(_provinceValue) && provinceValue.substring(0,2) !== formatedIndex return true;
    
    return false;
} 

if(objProvince){
    let error = false;
    error = provinceCheck(objProvince.value)
    
    if(error) {......
}
```

Problem with this is that the index of the array 28 and 30 are repeated, so I can't use the `indexOf` idea that I had.

Is there any other idea to refactor this? Maybe with some functional code. But I don't know any other solution.

Note that my solution above is broken because the array has a repeated index value 28 == 30

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "index value 28 == 30" ?

Comment: As there is a single problematic case, you might just branch on it first. Does that work for you? If you expect to be more, you can use a datastructure where the provinceValue is associated with a list of wrong values.

Comment: @phtrivier if you check the array, the index 28 is "MA" , and the index 30 is "MA" too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the logic by having a dictionary, and use such dictionary to verify the returned object value is a known key, and its value is correct.

```
const provinces = {
  "VI": "01",
  "AB": "02",
  "A": "03",
  "AL": "04",
  "AV": "05",
  "BA": "06",
  "PM": "07",
  "B": "08",
  "BU": "09",
  "CC": "10",
  "CA": "11",
  // the rest ...
};

objProvince = paramsData.find(element => element.name === "province");
let error = false;
if (objProvince && provinces.hasOwnProperty(objProvince.value))
  error = value.substring(0, 2) !== provinces[objProvince.value];
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd go the other way round - extract the index, and then check if the `_provinceValue` matches it:

```
function proviceCheck (_provinceValue) {
    const index = Number(provinceValue.substring(0,2)) - 1;

    return provinces[index] === _provinceValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to avoid the indexing error is generate a number alongside all of the province names by looping over all of the provinces in the provinces array, i would do that like this:

```
const provinces = ["VI" , "AB", "A", "AL", "AV", "BA", "PM"].map((a, b) => {'name': a, 'index': b}]);
```

now you could do `provinces[index].name` to get the name and `provinces[index].index`
to get its index